# I'm getting error while creating a procedure in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

My code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE proc_grade IS
    v varchar2(20);
    c varchar2(20);
    t integer(10);
    x integer(10);
   
CURSOR s IS
    SELECT total_marks,name,roll_no FROM STUD_MARKS ORDER BY roll_no;
BEGIN
    OPEN s;
        LOOP
            FETCH s INTO x,c,t;
                BEGIN
                    v:=grade(x);
                    INSERT INTO result VALUES(t,c,v);
                    dbms_output.put_line('ROLL_NO : '||t||'NAME: '||c||' CLASS: '||v);
                END;
           EXIT WHEN s%notfound;
        END LOOP;
   CLOSE s;
END;
```

Error that I am getting is as follows:

ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", line 581

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658

ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", line 567

ORA-06512: at "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2127

3. c varchar2(20);
4. t integer(10);
5. x integer(10);
6. 
7. CURSOR s IS

Answer (score 0):

It is not

```
CREATE OR REPLACE           proc_grade
```

but

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_grade
```

---

By the way, you could have done it way simpler by running only this instead of all the PL/SQL you wrote.

```
INSERT INTO result
   SELECT roll_no, name, grade (total_marks) 
   FROM stud_marks;
```